# Reordering index column according to date in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is sorted in descending order of date but the ID is not necessarily in ascending order, it looks something like (Note that some IDs might have the same date):

```
ID  Date  
1   2022-05-13
1   2022-05-13
1   2022-05-13
3   2022-05-13
3   2022-05-13
3   2022-05-13
3   2022-05-13
16  2022-07-14
16  2022-07-14
16  2022-07-14
2   2022-07-14
2   2022-07-14
2   2022-07-14
2   2022-07-14
2   2022-07-14
2   2022-07-14
9   2022-08-11
9   2022-08-11
```

And I would like to reorder the ID column so that the ID is in ascending column (so it preserves the number of rows of the original IDs), i.e.

```
ID  Date  
1   2022-05-13
1   2022-05-13
1   2022-05-13
2   2022-05-13
2   2022-05-13
2   2022-05-13
2   2022-05-13
3   2022-07-14
3   2022-07-14
3   2022-07-14
4   2022-07-14
4   2022-07-14
4   2022-07-14
4   2022-07-14
4   2022-07-14
4   2022-07-14
5   2022-08-11
5   2022-08-11
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Not sure if their is any direct way using any package/function to achieve the same result, but I think it does the job...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,1,1,3,3,3,3,16,16,16,2,2,2,2,2,2,9,9],
                    "Date":["date1"]*7+["date2"]*9 + ["date3"]*2})

lst = df["ID"].unique()
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({"ID":lst,
                        "Sorted_ID":range(1,len(lst)+1)})

df = df.merge(df_temp,on="ID",how="left")
del df["ID"]
```

Output of df;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.sort_values(by='ID').reset_index(drop=True)
```